# How to unstack data in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data. I am trying to create a bucket for each department with their employee count. what I am trying to get is the total number of employee with their ranking.

```
Department                  emp_rank
Electronics                   A1
Electronics                   A2
Electronics                   A4
Electronics                   B1
Electronics                   B2
Electronics                   B3
Electronics                   B4
Grocery                       B5
Grocery                       B6
Grocery                       B7
Grocery                       B8
Grocery                       B9  
Grocery                       B10
Grocery                       A1
Grocery                       A8
Pharmacy                      A2
Pharmacy                      A6
Pharmacy                      A8
Pharmacy                      A9
Pharmacy                      A4
Pharmacy                      A6

The goal is to unstack to get the following dataframe:

Department       A1-A9    B1-B6    B7-B10
Electronics      3         4         0        
Grocery          2         2         4       
Pharmacy         6         0         0
```

Comment: Is your data limited to these (A to E and 1 to 4 for each letter) or you need a more generic solution?

Comment: No acutaly it actually has A1-A9 and B1-B10

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.Department, df.emp_rank.str.extract('^(\D)+')[0].values)
```

Output:

```
col_0        A  B  C  D  E
Department                
Electronics  3  2  0  0  2
Grocery      3  3  0  0  2
Pharmacy     0  0  2  2  2
```

And then you can choose to rename accordingly.

Comment: I had to change the question. Your input is valueable.